# Variable: local scope, global scope or is it the JavaScript engine?

Tags: javascript

Here is something interesting I found while learning scope in javascript.

**Code**

```
var foo = "This is a global variable.";

var bar = function() {
    alert(foo);
    foo = "Value has been modified";
}

bar();
alert(foo);
```

This gives the normal response you think you would get, but if I change this one line:

**from:**

```
foo = "Value has been modified";
```

**to:**

```
var foo = "Value has been modified";
```

I get a value of undefined for foo, why is this? Since the function is global scope how come it doesn't accept the **var** keyword in front of it?

**Edit**

Now I understand basically what is happening the `var foo` in the function bar will gain most importance **because of the var keyword** and get hoisted up, but it will be hoisted up **without the value** it has been assigned.

Comment: Two words: [variable hoisting](http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting.html)

Comment: "I get a value of undefined for foo, why is this?" -- no you don't http://jsfiddle.net/up8bX/

Comment: Moving the var bar doesn't solve this issue though.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Understanding Global & Local Scope in Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11938961/understanding-global-local-scope-in-javascript)

Comment: It may be helpful to read what ECMA-262 says about [entering an execution context](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.4), in particular [declaration binding instantiation](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.5).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In a `var` statement, there are two parts to it - the actual declaration:

```
var foo //;
```

... and the assignment, which is optional:

```
= 1234567890;
```

If there is no assignment done to it, the variable (if not already defined) defaults to `undefined`.

---

The **variable declaration part** is moved to the top of the current scope (the start of the function), but **not the actual assignment** (so it's equivalent to the following):

```
var foo = "This is a global variable.";

var bar = function() {
    var foo; // undefined
    alert(foo); // yes, it's undefined
    foo = "Value has been modified"; // modify local, not global
}

bar();
alert(foo); // the global one
```

Functions create their own scope - for example take this:

```
var test = function ()
{   var bar = 1;
    console.log(bar); // 1
};
test();
console.log(bar); // ReferenceError: bar is not defined
```

Comment: but if they are hoisted to the top of the current scope, why doesn't it display the value it was assigned?

Comment: @htmltroll: because the actual assignment is not hoisted, only the definition.

Comment: when you say modify local, not global what do you mean? Doesn't foo modify the global starting variable foo? Because the function is in global scope.

Comment: I dislike the term "hoisting". It infers that the whole statement is "moved to the top of the scope" (i.e. execution context). What ECMA-262 says is that variable declarations are processed first, then statements and expressions are evaluated. Hence declared variable exist before they are assigned a value, even if an [initialiser](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-12.2) is used.

Comment: @htmltroll: the content of the function is in another scope - the `"Value has been modified"` only changes `foo` while inside the function.

Comment: @RobG: I've updated my answer to make it more clear.

Comment: @Qantas 94 Heavy: but how come the value is then changed and displays "Value has been modified"? doesn't it change the original value of global foo since the function it self is global?

Comment: @htmltroll—on entering the function, the local variable *foo* is created (among other things). The alert is then called and the value *undefined* displayed since *foo* hasn't yet been assigned any value. **Then** the local *foo* is assigned the value of "Value has been modified". The global *foo* is not modified since inside the function, *foo* resolves to the local variable, not the global one. Note that in ES5, variables are actually initialised to *undefined* when declared, which is really just a specification detail. They always behaved that way, although not specified in ECMA-262 ed3.

Answer (score 4):

By using `var`, you're telling the engine to use a **local** variable named foo, shadowing the global one.

The reason you get undefined on the `alert`, is that using `var` affects the whole scope, not just from that point onwards. You could've written:

```
var foo;
alert(foo);
foo = "Value has been modified";
```

Answer (score 4):

The JavaScript engine will parse your code and move `var` declarations to the top of its scope, but your string assignement to it will stay where it was. After the parse, here is how your code is interpreted:

```
var foo = "This is a global variable.";    

var bar = function() {
    var foo;
    alert(foo);
    foo = "Value has been modified";
}    

bar();
alert(foo);
```

As it creates a local variable without any value yet at the top of your function, your alert will show `undefined`.